# Howto create a partial mock using mockto-flex?

Tags: apache-flex, unit-testing, mockito

Is it posible to create a partial mock using mockito-flex?

Answer (score 1):

Mockito-flex does not support partial mocks at this point. However you can make your mock object call original functions.

given(someone.something(any())).will(callOriginal());

You could add a convenience function that makes your mock call originals for all public functions and properties.